# Looking to create a query in SQL that states

Tags: sql

i am relatively new to SQL and I'm looking to create a query that states how many records were created by those other than a certain "good" group of users (userids). If possible grouped by month as well. Any suggestions? I have some basic logic set out below.

Table is called newcompanies

```
SELECT COUNT(record_num), userid
FROM Newcompanies
WHERE userID <> (certain group of userIds)
GROUP BY Month
```

Will i be required to create a second table where the group of "good" userids is held

Comment: You are not required to create a table with second set of ID's, you could hard code them in the list.  This is not recommended though because if you have to edit the list it is more difficult then updating data in a table

Comment: so for example SELECT COUNT(record_num), userid
FROM Newcompanies
WHERE userID <> (userid1,userid2)
GROUP BY Month

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. Without knowing your exact columns, this will be a rough estimate.

```
SELECT id, 
DATEPART(MONTH, created_date) AS created_month, 
COUNT(*)
FROM your_table 
WHERE id NOT IN(
--hardcode userID's here
)
GROUP BY 
id, 
DATEPART(MONTH, created_date)
```

Or you could have a table with your good id's and then exclude those.

```
SELECT id, 
DATEPART(MONTH, created_date) AS created_month, 
COUNT(*)
FROM your_table 
WHERE id NOT IN(
SELECT id
from your_good_id_table
)
GROUP BY 
id, 
DATEPART(MONTH, created_date)
```

Comment: say i was looking for only users 3/4, would this logic stand?

company_num User_Id Create_Date
1 user1 5/11/2018
2 user2 5/11/2018
3 user3 4/11/2018
4 user4 4/11/2018   

SELECT User_ID, 
DATEPART(MONTH, Create_Date) AS created_month, 
COUNT(*)
FROM NewCompaniesTable
WHERE User ID NOT IN(user1, user2
)
GROUP BY 
User_ID, 
DATEPART(MONTH, Create_Date) sorry for the formatting, new to this.

Comment: You would still have two options: 1) put those two users into a table and use the 2nd example above, or hardcode those two userid's in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

-- if month is not a field in the table you will have to do a function to parse out the month that will depend on the sql database you are using, if it is MS SQL you can do Month(datefield)

```
SELECT COUNT(record_num), userid, Month
FROM Newcompanies
WHERE userID NOT IN (
    Select UserID
    from ExcludeTheseUserIDs
)
GROUP BY Month, userid
```